# Different broadcast times US vs UK

Tags: discussion, spoilers

Is there any way of marking questions on current series with whether they contain UK spoilers, even if they don't contain US spoilers, because the broadcast times are different?

The issue that alerted me to this is the once-upon-a-time questions. In the US, series 1 has finished, but in the UK, we are only on episode 7, so I daren't risk reading questions because I have no idea if anything in them will act as a spoiler for my enjoyment.

I know that it sometimes happens the other way too - Dr Who is normally broadcast here before it is shown over there, and the same issues could occur.

The problem is, there may be useful insight in the questions or answers to issues that I want to know about. And waiting until the series has finished here ( another 3 months ) is a frustrating prospect.

I suspect the answer is "nothing we can do", but suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because once this can of worms opens, it becomes a nightmare to manage.  There are dozens of countries, and each of them gets TV shows at different times.  Shows that are current in both the UK and US could be a season behind in Canada or Australia.

Just use spoiler tags for recent stuff in answers.  Then when you ask questions, make it clear what episode you're on, and that you want people to use spoiler tags in their answers for things that haven't aired in your region.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such thing as “UK spoilers” and “US spoiler”. Something is a spoiler if it would be a surprise to people who haven't seen the show. It doesn't matter where they live.

Stack Exchange is not a forum, it is a repository of questions and answers. The questions and answers are supposed to have lasting value. People will visit them for years.

In the long run, most people see the show way after it came out. So it doesn't matter where they live. **Choose whether to use spoilers based on your target audience** and not based on how recent a show is. If your question is intended not to spoil something for someone who hasn't seen the show, use spoiler markup, even if the show is from the 1960s. But don't overdo it, remember that **someone reading the question without the spoilers must have an idea of what it's about**.
And keep the question searchable — do not use workaround phrases such as “this character whose name would be a spoiler”: if the character's name is important, write it.